# What's the unipotent radical of the reduction of a bad orthogonal group?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups, p-adic-groups, orthogonal-groups

Consider a DVR $A$ with fraction field $K$ and residue field $k$.  Assume $2 \in A^\times$.  Let $Q: A^n \rightarrow A$ be a quadratic form defined over $A$.  Then one has the (naively defined) special orthogonal group scheme $SO_Q$ defined over $A$, which is nice (flat, etc.) under a unimodularity assumption.

But as it happens, my quadratic forms are not always so nice.  They are nondegenerate after base change to $K$, but are not necessarily nondegenerate over $A$.  Unfortunately, my now-standard reference on orthogonal group schemes -- Brian Conrad's treatment at http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/luminysga3.pdf -- says little about the group schemes $SO_Q$ in this case, as far as I can tell.

I wish to know the image of reduction, from $SO_Q(A)$ to $SO_Q(k)$.  I have my suspicions about the image containing the $k$-points of the unipotent radical of a certain parabolic definable from $Q$.  But I suspect that this has been considered before, so I'm writing to see if anyone has a good reference for special orthogonal groups in this somewhat degenerate but natural setting.

Does anyone know a reference where the structure of $SO_Q$ is considered in such a degenerate setting, especially regarding the unipotent radicals of special fibres?

Comment: Not an answer, but Brian also has another article that treats specifically special orthogonal groups over a ring: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/redgpZsmf.pdf. Have you looked into it?

Comment: @user94041: that paper proves more specialized things about special orthogonal groups over arithmetically interesting rings (such as $\mathbf{Z}$), but always assuming "fiberwise non-degeneracy" (ensuring all fibers are special orthogonal groups of non-degenerate quadratic spaces over fields, hence connected semisimple), so it doesn't apply to the situation of interest to Marty.

Comment: Marty, for your purposes with $A$-points you may as well define ${\rm{SO}}(Q)$ in your setup to be the schematic closure in ${\rm{GL}}_{n,A}$ of the closed $K$-subgroup ${\rm{SO}}(Q_K) \subset {\rm{GL}}_{n,K}$, and assume $Q$ is at least primitive over $A$. Try asking Wee Teck Gan (and when you summon the courage to consider residue characteristic 2, ask Sungmun Cho).

Comment: Thanks @nfdc23 -- I'll send Wee Teck a note to see if he knows.  I don't think this is in his papers with Yu, but I'll take another look there too.  And I might actually tackle p=2 sometime... so will keep Sungmun Cho in mind for the future.